# R： how to merge a vector that has been read into a existed vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have some file, and I want to merge one colume of them into a single vector, I use for-loop to read these file, but how to merge these colume. I just want to get the mean of these number.

Comment: Please show your code, example dataset etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) mentioned, it's hard to say without seeing some code or an example. That said, you might try `append()`:

Suppose you have two vectors you'd like to conjoin:

```
> a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> b <- c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

You might use `append()` like so:

```
> c <- append(a, b)
> c
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Then take the mean:

```
> mean(c)
[1] 5.5
```